# Dotnet swagger serializes Dictionary with long key wrong

Tags: .net, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

The following model:

```
public record Test
{
    public Dictionary<long, string> Dictoinary { get; set; }
}
```

used like:

```
public IActionResult Produce([FromBody]Test request) { ... }
```

Results in the following json body in swagger UI:

```
{
  "dictoinary": {
    "additionalProp1": "string",
    "additionalProp2": "string",
    "additionalProp3": "string"
  }
}
```

It's schema is obviously wrong:

```
Test {
  dictoinary {
    < * >: string
  }
  nullable: true
}
```

Promptly such request results in 500 as key `additionalProp1` cannot be serialized to a long.

Why does this happen? Can I plug-in somewhere during the serialization process of Swagger/Swashbuckle and correct this?

Note: this also happens for ints and I suspect it will happen for every type that cannot be assigned a value of `additionalPropN`